# PostgreSQL Multi column index best practice?

Tags: postgresql

Below is my table script.

```
CREATE TABLE tbloom AS
 SELECT
 (random() * 100)::int as i1,
 (random() * 1000)::int as i2,
 (random() * 10000)::int as i3,
 (random() * 100000)::int as i4,
 (random() * 1000000)::int as i5,
 (random() * 10000000)::int as i6,
 (random() * 50000000)::int as i7    
 FROM
 generate_series(1,300000000);
```

Below is my index script

```
 CREATE index btreeidx ON tbloom (i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6,i7);
```

Below is my select query

```
select * from tbloom  where i1=55 and i2=119 and i3=2196 limit 20;
```

Below is query analyze
[image: queryanalyze]

When execute it takes more than 1 mins and 30 seconds. How to optimize the query time, for that purpose which index is advisable ?
In my application user may choose any combination of data selection, which means user can query i2,i3 or i4,i6 like this.
Please suggest me to a correct way...

**Note:**
I have created the index with single column. It gives the result with in 300ms to 700ms, but as per my requirement user can choose any columns (1 or 2 or all columns)

Comment: Did you try one index for each column?

Comment: I cut it down to 3M rows, and i1...i5 and it runs in `Planning Time: 0.467 ms
 Execution Time: 0.084 ms` on a single index scan (PG12,RaspberryPi) , even without `vacuum analyze`

Comment: I can't reproduce this at all.  It uses the index quite eagerly.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have already tried with single column. When I search one column it gives with in 300 ms But as per my requirement I have to filter 1 or 2 or may be all columns to filter

Comment: @jjanes I am using PostgreSQL 12. I have tried in windows server

Comment: @wildplasser I can't understand. Did you say about the range partition ?

Comment: Any tuning done? IO speed? [ Answer: Yes, I stripped it down to 3M rows, and removed the last two columns (i6 and i7) ]

Comment: I think than @a_horse_with_no_name meant that you need 1 index per column, so a total of 7 different indexes. This way you do not need to access the table, only indexes.

Comment: I get the index used on Windows 10 using PostgreSQL 12.4, installed with EDB.  Although I only tried with 3e6 rows on that machine, I have a hard time seeing how that would matter.

Comment: This must be a Windows-Specifig Configuration Thing. Maybe a limited number of open file descriptors?

Comment: Did you try it with multiple indexes, each of a single column?

Comment: @jjanes  I have tried with 300000000 Row.... :(  I need  to improve performance for this much amount of rows only....

Comment: I also tried it with 3e7.  I am pretty sure nothing is going to fundamentally change just by adding more rows, other than the amount of hard-drive you would need to do it.

Comment: And it finally finished with 3e8 rows.  Still uses the index.

Answer (score 0):

The example you show should definitely use the index, because the first three index columns are used in the `WHERE` clause.

But both the name of table and index and your remark

> as per my requirement user can choose any columns (1 or 2 or all columns)

let me assume that you actually want a bloom index.

For this, you have to define the `bloom` extension in the database:

```
CREATE EXTENSION bloom;
```

and define the index with `USING bloom`:

```
CREATE index btreeidx ON tbloom USING bloom (i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7);
```

Then you can use any combination of the index columns in the `WHERE` condition, and the index can be used.

Comment: I don't think bloom will really work well here.  It is hard to get the correct number of bits when the number of columns being used is not predictable.  Even when you can tune it optimally (e.g. you always use exactly 4 of the 7 columns but in unknown combination), it doesn't work all that well.  Using BitmapAnd on single-column indexes is almost certainly going to be better here.

Comment: I have already check with the bloom also. But it's also takes the execution time like as the existing :(

Comment: @jjanes It may not support searches as well, but you need only a single index rather than one per column. So it is an interesting choice if you want to save storage space and overhead during data modifications.

Comment: @John I don't believe you.